# Modals Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

Estoy intentado usar un modal dialog de boostrap, con un form dentro. La cuestión es que al validar el form se me cierra el modal y regresa a la página en la que estaba, pero modificándome la url. Dado que trabajo con parámetros de la url me gustaría que esta no se modificase. 
¿Hay alguna forma de solucionarlo?

URL antes: http://localhost/E3-IISSI2-marlinbar/photo_detail_mine.php?photoId=8

URL tras realizar el form y darle a submit y cerrarse el modal: http://localhost/E3-IISSI2-marlinbar/photo_detail_mine.php?title=C%C3%A1lculo+de+flujo+de+campo&tags=sal%2C+pimienta&url=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.unsplash.com%2Fphoto-1515472071456-47b72fb3caff%3Fixlib%3Drb-1.2.1%26ixid%3DeyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9%26auto%3Dformat%26fit%3Dcrop%26w%3D634%26q%3D80&visibility=P%C3%BAblica

Comment: Cuando envias un formulario, siempre es recomendable enviarlo por el método de POST, adicionalmente puedes enviarla a la misma ruta con el parámetro photoId en el query string de la url, de esta manera no perderias el dato que necesitas

Comment: Hola, bienvenida a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour], de esa forma sabrás como funciona el sitio y de paso obtendrás tu primera medalla. Para poder ayudarte es necesario que copies y pegues el código relevante para poder reproducir el problema y detallar dónde puesa estar el error. Puede leer [mcve] como referencia. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Valida con Javascript:

```
    function validaCamposPHP(){

      if (nombreForma.value == "" || apellidoForma.value == "")
         {
               $("#msgForma").text('Escribe en los campos vacios por favor');
         }
      else{
         document.getElementById("formulario").submit();
         }

                              }
```

En el ejemplo mi form tiene un ID llamado formulario, estoy validando dos campos: nombreForma y apellidoForma, si estan vacios me muestra un mensaje, y si no envía el formulario.